# Pymongo query significantly slower through AWS Lambda

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, mongodb-query, pymongo

When I run a query through Robo 3T, mongod, or pymongo using the command line, the query takes 50 milliseconds to return the results. Running the same query using pymongo in AWS Lambda takes 15-16 seconds. All queries are not this slow, just address queries in my case (queries for a name take under 1 second). I'm using python 3.6, pymongo 3.7, and mongodb 3.6.

I don't believe it's a cold start issue because I run 2 queries in a row, this being the second query, and the first query still takes less than a second. Also, I've tried running it multiple times in a row and I get the same results every time. The function only uses up 57MB of the 128MB allotted, so I don't believe it could be a CPU issue, and increasing the CPU didn't change the speed at all.

MongoDB query

```
db.getCollection('CA').find({'$and': [{'OWNER_ZIP': {'$regex': '^95120'}},{'OWNER_STREET_1': '123 MAIN STREET'}]})
```

pymongo query

```
cursor = list(db_unclaimed.find({'$and': [{'OWNER_ZIP': {'$regex': '^95120'}},{'OWNER_STREET_1': '123 MAIN STREET'}]}).skip(0).limit(50))
```

Python function I'm using

```
def searchAddress(zipcode, address, page_size, page_num):
    print('Searching by address...')
    print(address)
    skips = page_size * (int(page_num) - 1)
    cursor = list(db_unclaimed.find({'$and': [{'OWNER_ZIP': {'$regex': zipcode}},{'OWNER_STREET_1': address}]}).skip(skips).limit(page_size))
    for document in cursor: print(document)
    return cursor
```

I would expect the query to take close to the same amount of time in lambda that it does using the other 3 methods, even if it might a bit slower. Does anyone have any ideas as to what could be causing this?

Comment: Please provide info about the database server; my first thought is cache.

Comment: I'm just using a lowest tier database through M-clusters.com / cloudclusters.io - mongodb 3.6, 60GB SSD, 2 CPU cores, 2GB RAM. How do I diagnose if it's a cache issue?

Comment: @cdstamper Does that help give you an idea as to what the issue could be?

Comment: Does anyone out there have any ideas? Is there any other info I can provide?